# php session_id change on header redirect

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, session-cookies

What I am trying to do is increment the value inside the COOKIE in every redirect... but every time I check if the cookie exists it doesn't.

I try to do it with a SESSION also, but the session_id changes in each redirect (I am guessing that the redirect create a new session for some reason )

This is my code

```
<script language="javascript">
    var popexurl = "<?php echo $PopExitUrl ?>";
    if(popexurl != ""){
    (function() {
        setTimeout(function() {

            <?php 

                if (isset($_COOKIE["count"]))
                {
                    //cheak user refreshes

                             $cookie = (int)++$_COOKIE['count'];
                             setcookie("count", $cookie, time()+3600);

                }
                else 
                {
                       setcookie("count", 1, time()+3600);
                       $cookie=0;

                }

            ?>

        var __redirect_to = '<?php echo $PopExitUrl; ?>';//

        var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;
        for(_i in _tags) {
            _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);
            for(_i2 in _els) {
                if((_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' && _els[_i2].type != 'submit' && _els[_i2].type != 'image') || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') continue;
                _els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}
            }
       }

        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          window.scrollTo(0,0); 
          document.getElementById('ExitBackDiv').style.display = 'block';       
             document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
                setTimeout(function() 
                {
                   window.location = __redirect_to;
                }, 500);
           },5);
            <?php
            if ($PopupMessage == ""){
            $PopupMessage= "\\n**********************\\nWAIT! WAIT! WAIT! WAIT!\\n\\n**********************\\n\\nDont Miss This LAST CHANCE to become Financially Secure and CHANGE YOUR Lifestyle!!!\\n\\n...Click STAY ON THIS PAGE to activate your LIMITED time offer!";}

                    ?>

      var popmsg = "<?php echo $PopupMessage ?>";  


    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1)
    {
    //setTimeout('window.location="'+__redirect_to+'"', 10);
     window.alert(popmsg); 
     return popmsg;


      }
    else
     {
            return popmsg;

            }

        }            
        }, 500);

    })();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`session_start();` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a `GET` or `POST` request, or passed via a `cookie`.

PHP: [session_start()](http://php.net/session_start)

Comment: so what?, i know what session_start() does

Comment: So, you do know that you have sent headers `html` before `setcookie()`?